# Similar Go functions appending strings and arrays do not behave as expected

Tags: algorithm, go

I have two Go functions:

```go
func permutation(prefix, str []int) {
    n := len(str)
    if n == 0 {
        fmt.Println(prefix)
    } else {
        for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
            permutation(
                append(prefix, str[i]),
                append(str[0:i], str[i+1:]...),
            )
        }
    }
}

func perms(prefix, str string) {
    n := len(str)
    if n == 0 {
        fmt.Println(prefix)
    } else {
        for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
            perms(
                prefix+string(str[i]),
                string(str[0:i])+string(str[i+1:]),
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The first takes an array of ints, the second takes a string. They both then calculate all permutations of the array, or the string.

I can run them like so:

```
permutation([]int{}, []int{1, 2, 3})
perms("", "123")
```

Their output is not the same:

```
$ go run main.go
[1 2 3]
[1 3 3]
[3 3 3]
[3 3 3]
[3 3 3]
[3 3 3]
123
132
213
231
312
321
```

I guess there is some nuance to appending arrays that I am missing. I can't seem to figure it out. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `str1+str2` does return new (unrelated in terms of memory) string, `append` doesn't behave this way. For example `append(str[0:i], str[i+1:]...)` will destroy original content of `str`, overwriting `str[i:]` with `str[i+1:]`. This is because `str[0:i]` will have capacity to append `str[i+1:]` without allocating new buffer.

The solution would be to create a completely new array in every iteration. At least for `str`, as `append(prefix, str[i])` is immune to this problem. For example:

```
for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
    var s []int
    s = append(s, str[0:i]...)
    s = append(s, str[i+1:]...)
    permutation(append(prefix, str[i]), s)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/lXwu39AA0V

More about slices and mechanism of append:

http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

https://blog.golang.org/slices